# Format time durations to ISO 8601

Tags: r, lubridate, iso8601, time-format

How can I express time durations (e.g. as returned by `lubridate::dminutes()` or `lubridate::duration()`) in the [ISO 8601 duration format](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001437-13/reference/r_iso_8601_duration_format.htm)?

Package `lubridate` can **parse** ISO 8601 durations:

```r
lubridate::duration("PT1H3M")
# "3780s (~1.05 hours)"
```

But I wouldn't know how to reverse this, i.e. how to **format** or deparse to ISO 8601.

Desired output in pseudo code:

```r
library(magrittr)

"PT1H3M" %>%
  lubridate::duration() %>%
  format_to_iso8601() # pseudo function
# [1] "PT1H3M"
```

I saw that there used to exist [`lubridate::format_ISO8601()`](https://rdrr.io/github/hadley/lubridate/man/format_ISO8601.html) that might have been able to do that, but it's not part of the current package version anymore.

Similarily, [`parsedate::format_iso_8601()`](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/parsedate) does format to ISO 8601, but only dates or datetimes, not durations.

---

## EDIT

Seems like `lubridate::as.period()` might do for a workaround:

```r
iso_duration <- "PT1H3M" %>%
  lubridate::duration() %>%
  lubridate::as.period() %>%
  stringr::str_replace_all("\\s", "") %>%
  stringr::str_c("PT", .)

iso_duration
# [1] "PT1H3M0S"

iso_duration %>%
  lubridate::duration()
# [1] "3780s (~1.05 hours)"
```

Comment: Is `as.numeric(lubridate::dminutes(1.2))/60` returning you the expected output?

Comment: @tmfmnk that gives me `1.2`, I need the output to be `PT1M12S` for your example